# What entities must get involved when building a new home or modifying the exterior of a home?

Tags: exterior, renovation

When constructing a new home or renovating a home, and the exterior of the home is changing in some way, what entities (government, insurance companies, home owner, etc..) or organizations must be involved?

Someone told me that you must comply with city or municipality building codes.

If government must be involved, is this county specific or city specific usually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code making bodies refer to them as the "Authority Having Jurisdiction" and they could be municipal, county or state depending on where you live.

I had to go to one entity to get a well and septic permit, another one to get an address for my property and a third to get my building permits.

It is an arduous process but is required to ensure safe building methods are used.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Building official, zoning official, sanitarian or department of public health and if natural water ways or wetlands are involved, the wetlands commission, EPA and department of environmental protection. Usually a good general contractor will know the proper route to success.